# ¿Cómo funciona el StreamWriter en c#?

Tags: c#

esta línea de código qué significa?

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "/agenda.txt", true);
```

el `true` es para qué? y `"/agenda.txt"` es el nombre del archivo de texto que se está creando ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)  en la documentación con respecto a sus constructores los especifica , es decir el constructor que plantea es [StreamWriter(String, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) donde el primer parámetro será la  ruta de acceso completa al archivo y como segundo parámetro un valor `booleano` .

> Es `True` si se desea agregar datos al archivo , y `FALSE` para 
>   sobrescribir el archivo. Si el archivo especificado no existe, este
>   parámetro no tiene ningún efecto y el constructor crea un nuevo
>   archivo.

Comment: excelente respuesta,gracias!